# No descargo la totalidad de información de precios de una web

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

estoy empezando con el web scrapping y quiero obtener precios de una web que tiene varias páginas, tengo el siguiente código:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.plazavea.com.pe/electrohogar/lavado/"

client = urlopen(url)
page_html = client.read()
client.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

with open('./page.html', mode='w') as f:
    f.write(str(page_soup))

page_soup.find("a", { "class": "Showcase__name" })

for div in page_soup.findAll("a", { "class": "Showcase__name" }):
    print(div.text.strip())

for div in page_soup.findAll("div", { "class": "Showcase__priceBox__amount" }):
    inner_div = div.find("div", { "class": "Showcase__salePrice" })
    print(inner_div.text.strip()[3:])
```

Obtengo descripciones y precios de 20 productos (no todos pertenecen a la página1), pero quiero obtener información de la totalidad de productos de la web.
Ya intenté con la url de la página 2

```
url = "https://www.plazavea.com.pe/electrohogar/lavado?page=2"
```

pero obtengo exactamente los mismos resultados.

Agradeceré sus sugerencias.

Comment: No me queda del todo claro cómo cambias las url dado que la variable llamada `url2` no se ocupa en el bloque de codigo que posteaste.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, quise mencionar que intente probando ```url = "https://www.plazavea.com.pe/electrohogar/lavado?page=2"``` pero obtuve los mismos resultados.

Comment: as intentado crear un diccionario o una lista con los productos ya escrapiados?? asi no se repetiran.... ejemplo por su href

Comment: Intenta partir por algo mas pequeño y compara los contenidos de la variable page_html con ambas url, a ver si cambia.

Comment: El contenido de page_html es exactamente el mismo con ambas url.